# Если я использую лишь 1 предложение из цитаты, нужно ли мне будет ставить многоточие после него?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, цитирование

> Никакая внешняя прелесть не может быть полной, если она не оживлена
>   внутренней красотой. Красота души разливается подобно таинственному
>   свету по телесной красоте

предложение будет завершено, а цитата - нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно никакого многоточия. Ваше предложение — это будет тоже цитата. Оценивать её можно по-разному: как новую цитату из изначального текста-источника или как "цитату цитаты".

В любом случае нет причины воспринимать цитату как некоторую неделимую единицу текста, сокращение которой нужно как-то пунктуационным образом подчёркивать.